# Can not access Apache server from LAN

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I have tried everything to get it to work but i still can not access my website (localhost) from my LAN.
I am using Apache2.4 with PHP7.1.
What is wierd is that after I type my computer IP on my phone, the URL changes from "ip" to "www.ip/"(I have a .htaccess file) but gives me error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. I am using Chrome.

```
DirectoryIndex  index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

order allow,deny
deny from 46.101.200.204
allow from all
```

Comment: I would say you need to either get rid of that last RewriteRule, or set up a domain name for your server instead of accessing by direct IP. The rule as it stands is redirecting you to a broken URL if you come in using the IP, exactly as you are seeing.

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? What behaviour do you see now?

Comment: I turned off the rewrite engine and I still can't access the website from my phone.

Comment: @KarlReid do you have any clue?

Comment: How is your vhost set? You are mixing 2.2 rules with 2.4. You need to remove the bottom 3 lines and use `Require all granted` and `Require not ip 46.101.200.204`

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shove "www.ip" in your hosts file on your client if you're going to insist on that name via mod_rewrite. If you decide to stop doing that, you'll need to also clear your browser cache since you picked a permanent redirect.